# AutoResizeTextView Not Working as Expected

Tags: android, xml, textview

I'm trying to use the third party AutuResizeTextView library and unfortunately it isn't working correctly. In the first case where I use it I'm changing the text inside an AutoResize view and whenever I set new text the view's size becomes much smaller. The second case is where I have a list of AutoResize views and only some of the text re-sizes correctly. All of this is being done using XML.

Link to the library: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView

First case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <com.lb.auto_fit_textview.AutoResizeTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/place_info_container"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <com.lb.auto_fit_textview.AutoResizeTextView 
            android:id="@+id/place_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <com.lb.auto_fit_textview.AutoResizeTextView  
            android:id="@+id/place_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/place_name"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: ListView problems have probably something common to recycling view process - items are reused, and probably AutoResizeTextView isn't redrawn, what is necessary to calculate new text size.

Comment: you need to resize text to small when it's large? @Evan

Comment: @Shadow yes that is my goal

Comment: @Specku do you know how I could fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know [this custom](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) view works really nice - it's the same feature as library which you use. Moreover there are a lot of implemetations of auto resize text view. If you need results and don't really care which solution you use, maybe try to use another one.

Moreover 'Grantland' implementation works good with ListView (or it worked few months ago).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your text when it's too large, no need to use third party library at all..

Simply follow this. Hope this works.

```
 TextView productName;

   productName.setText("Give a very large text anc check it");
    productName.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int lengthCount = productName.getLineCount(); //check whether your line count goes more
            if(lengthCount == 2){ //check how much lines maximum it goes and give your wish.
                productName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16); //reduce font size
            }
    }});
```

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't want to constantly set it to 16sp